# Software that creates .exe files that when executed download a file from the internet

Tags: windows

I have a file sitting in my Amazon S3 bucket and I have CloudFront all set up. A lot of people don't go through with the download when and I assume that is because it's a 4GB file and it takes a while to download.

I need a program with which I can make a small executable for them to download and when they launch it, it automatically downloads the big file. Kind of like a launcher or an installer. Preferably a free program but I'm willing pay for one if there is no free option.

Comment: Do you need a graphical user interface? If yes, what should it show?

Comment: Even with the downloader, it's still a 4GB file that's gonig to take long time. Maybe hosting it on a torrent server would be a better choice?

Comment: Nicolas, a UI would be nice. The only important thing is to make it clear that the file is downloading.
Ring, I know it will still take a long time to download but I think that if it's not a huge download from the browser, but something like a launcher or installer, people might be more willing to wait for it, since they have already downloaded the smaller file.